# Normalize file path in JavaScript front-end

Tags: javascript, path

#### The short story:

Is there simple way to normalize file path in JavaScript, like in Java we have `Paths.get("/a/b/../c").normalize()` so `/a/../../c` would become `/c`. I seen many same questions here, but they are Node.js solutions, and I need pure JS or JQuery approach so it can be used in browser.

#### The long story:

I have a file server with web UI, that allows to browse files and download them. UI is written in spring and accessible at `mysite.com/ui/`

The file storage located at `mysite.com/files/` which is plain Apache directory, so its possible to get direct link to file.

The real storage directory on server is `/var/www/files`

Path passing to back-end as `mysite.com/ui/?path=/a/../../c`, so back-end will normalize `path` variable separately to `/c` and then append it to base dir and so retrieving content of `/home/storage/c`, so it works perfectly.

The problem comes when user tries to download file like this with direct link. I.e. if user tries to download `/a/../../c/d` file from file server root, it appending to base storage url, which `mysite.com/files/`, and it becomes `mysite.com/files/a/../../c/d` so it will point to `/var/www/d` instead of `/var/www/files/d` so file can't be downloaded even if it is visible from web UI.

So I need to normalize relative file path first on front-end like on back-end when retrieving content of directory but I don't know how it can be done in JS. Is there function for it, or I have to write my own one?

Comment: [`new URL("https://example.com/files/a/../../c/d")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon it will normalize url and not relative path, so it will point to `https://example.com/c/d` but not `https://example.com/files/c/d`

Comment: But `/files/a/../../c/d` _is_ `/c/d` and _not_ `/files/c/d`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon formally, it is. But, as I mentioned, I want to use `mysite.com/files/` as root url for all files. So if I have `mysite.com/files/` and `a/../../c/d`, I need to build an absolute link that will point to `mysite.com/files/c/d/`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own function on JS. It might be not what "path normalization" stands for, but anyway its exactly what I need

```
function normalizePath(path) {
    // remove multiple slashes
    path = path.replace(/\/+/g, '/');
    // remove leading slash, will be added further
    if (path.startsWith("/"))
        path = path.substring(1)
    // remove trailing slash
    if (path.endsWith("/"))
        path = path.slice(0, -1);
    let segments = path.split("/");
    let normalizedPath = "/";
    for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segments.length; segmentIndex++) {
        if (segments[segmentIndex] === "." || segments[segmentIndex] === "") {
            // skip single dots and empty segments
            continue;
        }
        if (segments[segmentIndex] === "..") {
            // go up one level if possible
            normalizedPath = normalizedPath.substring(0, normalizedPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            continue;
        }
        // append path segment
        if (!normalizedPath.endsWith("/"))
            normalizedPath = normalizedPath + "/"
        normalizedPath = normalizedPath + segments[segmentIndex];
    }
    return normalizedPath;
}
```

Still, I won't mark this as accepted answer as it's more of a quick fix, and I'm not JS expert so it definitely must be more elegant solution.